# Calling a post mockjax service with jquery $.post not returning value

Tags: javascript, jquery, mockjax

I am attempting to call a Mockjax 'post' endpoint through jQuery $.post method as below

service.js

```
$.mockjax({
    url: '/api/callfor/data',
    type: 'post',
    responseTime: 1000,
    contentType: 'text/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    responseText: {
        success: true,
        data: 'Hello World'
    }
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Mock Ajax call</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mockjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $.post('/api/callfor/data', {}, function (resp) {
            var html = (resp.success) ? 'Your data is ' + resp.data : 'No data received';
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However on calling the method, the resp always coming as undefined.
What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of data being requested or rather say that the type of data endpoint provides i.e. JSON was not mentioned in the call.

So changing the post call to

```
 $.post('/api/callfor/data', {}, function (resp) {
            var html = (resp.success) ? 'Your data is ' + resp.data : 'No data received';
        }, 'json');
```

This returns the data.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue when I updated my project's jQuery version from [1.12.4](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js) to [2.2.4](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js). The project had been using [jquery-mockajax version 2.0.1](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-mockjax@2.0.1/src/jquery.mockjax.js). `$.post` calls to URLs mocked with jquery-mockjax were resulting in a Type Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reload')

By updating to the latest (as of this time) jquery-mockjax - [v2.6.1](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-mockjax@2.6.1/src/jquery.mockjax.js) - I no longer experienced the error.